# GCP: Resource Name vs URL : Inconsistent matching

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud, google-cloud-iam

**For a Resource Name find the appropriate HTTP Rest URL for it.**

With the help of the below Google Doc, for some resources name to URL mapping is working fine

- Doc:
  https://cloud.google.com/apis/design/resource_names#resource_name_vs_url

Example:

- Name Format:
  //cloudresourcemanager.googleapis.com/organizations/ORGANIZATION_NUMBER
- URL:
  https://cloudresourcemanager.googleapis.com/v1/organizations/ORGANIZATION_NUMBER

Basically adding HTTPS scheme before the name and the API major version before the resource path this works fine.

**But the problem is this conversion scheme is not consistent for some resources if we form URL with this approach it will differ from the actual URL**

Example:

- Name Format: //compute.googleapis.com/projects/PROJECT_ID/
- Formed URL: https://compute.googleapis.com/v1/projects/PROJECT_ID/
- URL in Google Doc: https://compute.googleapis.com/**compute**/v1/projects

Compute Engine API Reference: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1

Other resources apart from compute also have actually different URL from the generated one using the above method.

Queries are:

1. Apart from the mentioned way is there any way to map resource names to URL
2. What are the best practices in such conversion
3. Apart from manually mapping each name to URL is there any generic way
4. Is there any API which provides this mapping, Like pass, a resource name and URL for it will be returned(On the internet I didn't found one)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google APIs have a [discovery document](https://developers.google.com/discovery/v1/reference/apis).

In that JSON file, there are 2 fields revelant for this question: `rootUrl` and `servicePath`.

To construct a proper URL for the API, concatenate both values.

More details in the [discovery service docs](https://developers.google.com/discovery).

Comment: After closely looking for some time into the Discovery Service, facing an inconsistency issue. 1. Response of the discovery service is really long if we are interested in a just a single REST method 2. As per the docs partial response will be a solution to this issue. 3. Partial response is not working properly with all the resources i tried 4. Working Fine With Discovery Service: https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/compute/v1/rest?fields=rootUrl,servicePath 5. Doesn't work with Resource manager: https://cloudresourcemanager.googleapis.com/$discovery/rest?version=v1&fields=rootUrl

Comment: That does not seem to be working as intended, You could raise an issue with Google: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187192&template=1162689  The provided libraries (https://developers.google.com/api-client-library) download the whole discovery document and cache it locally to avoid having to fetch it every time.